# Тетя, тетка, жена дяди

Tags: тезаурус

Умершую вдовствующую Королеву Фабиолу как минимум дважды назвали *тётей* нынешнего Короля Бельгийцев Филиппа.
На самом деле Филипп - племянник её ранее умершего мужа, Короля Бодуэна (сын его младшего брата Альберта).

Вопрос. Насколько правомерно тут "тетя" или "тетка". Не запутало ли оно вас?
Речь все-таки об особах августейших, неточности в терминах родства нежелательны.
(+)
*Видимо, это был не самый удачный перевод английского aunt-in-law - или французского belle-tante (хотя последнее, кажется, не официальный термин).*

Answer (score 1):

А почему неправомерно, если тетка- это сестра отца или матери, а также жена дяди. Я сначала думала, что это разговорное, но проверила по словарям - верно (в словаре С.И. Ожегова, Н.Ю. Шведовой, У Ушакова и Ефремовой то же самое)

http://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ushakov-term-75330.htm

Так что, вероятно, перевод правильный.

Comment: Ну хотя бы потому, что это связано с трактовкой престолонаследования.
Ну хорошо, тётка трактуется как жена дяди. А "тётя"?

Comment: Это то же самое. Перврначально было тётя- из детской речи, подобно папа, мама,дядя.Вначале имело форму тета, от него с суфф.-ък- тетъка (уменьшит.)- тётка. В совр. языке утратило оттенок уменьшительности. Обе формы используются равноправно.